# ASP.Net GridView - fire datarow click event except on checkbox selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm implenting a functionality of inbox where i have a GridView and code as follows:

```
<asp:GridView Width="100%" ID="grdInbox" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" 
         runat="server" onrowcommand="grdInbox_RowCommand" GridLines="None" CssClass="mGrid"
         PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
            onrowdatabound="grdInbox_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="mailSelector" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="Sender" HeaderText="Sender" SortExpression="Sender" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Subject" HeaderText="Subject" SortExpression="Subject" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Size" HeaderText="Size" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Sent" HeaderText="Sent at" SortExpression="Sent" />

        </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
```

Also I have registered "onclick" event as follows:

```
e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = "location.href='MailContent.aspx?id=" + e.Row.UniqueID + "'";
```

But here even if i select a checkbox onclick event gets fired. i dont want the checkbox to fire this event. It should just act for selection of rows. What shall I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I hope, that here you can find an explanation](http://interviews.dotnetthread.com/2009/02/making-gridview-rows-or-individual.html) how to solve your issue.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"This site can’t be reached | interviews.dotnetthread.com’s server IP address could not be found."*